# Migrating MSSql into Mysql

Tags: mysql, sql-server, migration, mysql-workbench

I am using MySql workbench migration wizard and when i get to the last step of wizard i get errors while migrating bigger tables:

```
ERROR: `master`.`mtm_flat_request`:Found record bigger than max_allowed_packet
```

If i increase size of max_allowed_packet I get different error:

```
ERROR: `master`.`mtm_flat_request`:Not enough memory to allocate insert buffer of size 1073741824
ERROR: `master`.`mtm_flat_request`:Failed copying 39135 rows
```

Server is on cloud and has 4gb of ram. Any suggestions what i can do in order to avoid this problem?

Comment: The only solution is to change `max_allowed_packet` in the mysql config

Comment: But if i increase it i get this second error?

Comment: see here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/24501432/migration-issues-ms-sql-mysql-insert-buffer-memory

Comment: Hmm i saw that post but dont know which parameter should i change with that formula?

Comment: Well, MySQL Workbench trying allocate 1GB buffer size, so maybe you should consider increase amount of RAM if you want copy such big data?